# Apache: Serve http traffic over https

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

Using apache.
I have a demo of a webapp that usually uses https.  However, for the demo, I want all traffic to be on http even if a user hits https.

I have added the following entry and it works if you go to http:// AAAA.com:443, but doesn't work if you go to https:// AAAA.com.

It gives you this error:

```
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

Here is my current setup:

```
<VirtualHost 111.111.111.1:443>
    ServerName test.AAAA.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/AAAA.com
</VirtualHost>
```

How do you redirect the https->http without encountering the SSL error. In other words, turn off ssl for https://

Answer (score 2):

You don’t.

If you want a redirect from `https://wherever` to `http://wherever`, then port 443 of `wherever` actually needs to be serving HTTPS, even if it’s just enough to present a certificate and unconditionally redirect. Doing this means that `http://wherever:443` won’t work, but why on earth would anybody expect it to?

There might be a custom server somewhere which is smart enough to differentiate between SSL negotiation and an plain HTTP request and do the right thing in either case, but it’s not a standard part of Apache.

You have three options:

- Configure the application on both 80 and 443 over HTTP and HTTPS respectively
- Configure it on only one of these and configure the other to redirect
- Configure it on only one of these and do without the redirects (make sure that nothing points to the other one)

(HTTP and HTTP-over-SSL are completely different protocols on the wire: you can’t expect something which hasn’t been specifically designed to talk both on the same port to be able to do that).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is the browser that is requesting a https session (its in the URL). Without actually talking SSL on 443, you won't be able to redirect the browser to use non-SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just change the VirtualHost to listen on port 80, replace https with http and call it a day?